# How to get a time stamp posted?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to get a time stamp in the format of "posted: ten minutes ago" or "posted yesterday" or "posted three days ago" etc.  I want to have an activity with a button and when the button is clicked I want to open a new activity and display the time stamp in the format I explained in the new activity.   This is what I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2.class);
                i.putExtra("currentTime", currentTime);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And activity two which I want to display the time stamp in the above format:

```
public class Main2 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        long currentTime = extras.getLong("currentTime");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.GergorianCalendar class to get the date, hour second and day and calculate the appropriate verb

[java.util.GergorianCalendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Android provides a `DateUtils` class that has static methods for getting "relative time" strings (what you are describing). See for example [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29). They're not the most intuitive methods ever, but they should be sufficient for what you want.